# Scraping with Python, extracting number

Tags: python, web-scraping

It is my first Python code, so any help would be appreciated.

I have been able to scrape a webpage, to reach a set of texts as output. I am not able to move further from there.

**Code:**

```
page = requests.get("https://www.traderscockpit.com/?pageView=live-nse-advance-decline-ratio-chart")

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

Adv = soup.find(class_="advDec")

Adv
```

**Result**

```
<p class="advDec"><a href="/?pageView=nse-top-gainers" title="Click to view list of Advanced stocks">Advanced:</a> 736</p>
```

*I now dont know how to extract the number 736, that lies between a and p on the right.
Can you please help?*

Comment: This does not seem like the most appropriate "first code" task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
page = requests.get("https://www.traderscockpit.com/?pageView=live-nse-advance-decline-ratio-chart")

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

Adv = soup.find('p', class_="advDec")

Adv.text
```

Comment: BTW if you want to extract links or other attribs you can use `adv['href']` to get link or `adv['title']` to get title ot etc